# (Bootstrap 3) <dl> list breaks if there's a floating image before it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

By default in Bootstrap 2 there was no 'content: " ";' property in dl styling. But now it is added as default. By disabling that content: " "; or display: table it fixes the problem. But I do not want to edit bootstrap files. I don't even know what that content: " "; does.

Is there any simple and correct method on fixing that?

Comment: An image of code is no good. We need real code.

Comment: You want me to copy and paste entire HTML and CSS here? Don't think that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) property applies to the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, and is used to insert generated content before and/or after the content of an element. Since you claim that disabling this property gives you the desired behaviour you can just override these rules in your own stylesheet:

```
.dl-horizontal dd:before, .dl-horizontal dd:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that, but it will override all dl's then. What if I will need that default setting somewhere? Overriding Bootstrap properties like this don't think is best solution.

Comment: Then give the relevant `<dl>` elements a class and replace the above rules with your class name.

Comment: Yeah I added a dl-custom class for it. I chose your answer.

Answer (score 0):

width is not working properly so in `:after` `display: table;` is added to fix the problem and in `:after` pseudo element there must be defined `content:`